# Slick Slider Multiple Classes with On JS Function But Different - slidesToShow and slidesToScroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

Hello genius people out there . 
my goal is can i put a multiple classes in slick slider but only one JS function  and also different `slidesToShow:` and `slidesToScroll` according to their class .

please anyone can take me to the top . would much appreciate ((: thanks